# Post Parameters in Android Request

Tags: android, post, parameters, request

I am doing an Android application and I have a problem doing my request against my own server. I have made the server with Play Framework, and I get the parameters from a Json:

```
 response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("application/json; charset=utf-8");        
 JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(); 
 JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(getBody(request.body)); 
 Long id =jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsLong();
```

When I make my GET request against my server, all is ok. But when I make a POST request, my server return me an unknown error, something about there is a malformed JSON or that it is unable to find the element.

> private ArrayList NameValuePair> params;
>
> private ArrayList NameValuePair> headers;
>
> ...
>
> case POST:
>
> ```
>   HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(host);
>   // Add headers
>   for(NameValuePair h : headers) 
>   {
>        postRequest.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
>   }
>   if(!params.isEmpty())
>   {
>        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
>   }
>   executeRequest(postRequest, host);
>   break;
> ```

I have tried to do with the params of the request, but it was a failure:

> if(!params.isEmpty()) 
>   {
>        HttpParams HttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
>
> ```
>  for (NameValuePair param : params)
>  {
>       HttpParams.setParameter(param.getName(), param.getValue());
>  }                
>  postRequest.setParams(HttpParams); }
> ```

And there is the different errors, depends on the request I make. All of them are  'play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException':

- 'com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException'
- 'This is not a JSON Object'
- 'Expecting object found: "id"'

I wish somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way to send a HTTP Post.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Your URL here");
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(paramsJson));
httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

You would be better off using the JSON String directly instead of parsing it here. Hope it helps

Comment: But I have a List<NameValuePair> params for adding to the request. If I make my own JSON in a String format, I must do it manually? Thanks for all.

Comment: Hi Neo, I have posted the JSON as per your suggestion. How can I query the parameters in ASP.Net server.?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this,It may help u

     public void executeHttpPost(String string) throws Exception
    {
        //This method for HttpConnection
           try
          {
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

             HttpPost request = new HttpPost("URL");

           List<NameValuePair> value=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

           value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",string));

           UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);

           request.setEntity(entity);

          client.execute(request);

           System.out.println("after sending :"+request.toString());

           }
        catch(Exception e)  {System.out.println("Exp="+e);
          }

 }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, because on my code params is a List<NameValuePair>. Obviouslym that's not work for me :S Very thanks anywhere =)

Comment: E/Error Users(371): Error 500: : 'play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException',01-22 10:43:06.582: E/Error Users(371): message: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use jsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON near idUser1=57&idUser2=65
E/Error Users(371): '
E/Error Users(371): Error 500: :   'play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException',
E/Error Users(371): message: 'This is not a JSON Object.'
E/Error Users(371): Error 500: :   'play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException',
E/Error Users(371): message: 'Expecting object found: "name"'

Comment: Sorry for the bad lecture.

Comment: What JSON? I have an ArrayList of NameValuePair and the only thing I can do is postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8)); I dont do any JSON in the Android Application. (The errors are from server).